# keyListener stops working when AcionListener starts

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keylistener

Im trying to bring up password dialog when VK_ESCAPE is pressed and it works at first . But as soon as any JButtons are pressed focus ignores keyListenrs here is my code is there any Quick fixes for this .

```
package AVAG;

/**
 *
 * @author allan walls
 */
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import static org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init;

public class avagui extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    JButton app1, app2, app3, app4;
    //ImageIcon test1 =new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Volunteering.jpg"));
    //websitelink link = new websitelink();
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2, 2, -700, 0);

    Web1 web1 = new Web1();
    Web2 web2 = new Web2();
    Web3 web3 = new Web3();
    Web4 web4 = new Web4();
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(6, 32);
       // keyboardgui kg = new keyboardgui();

    public avagui() {

        init();
        //setUndecorated(true);
    }

    private void init() {

        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        pane.addKeyListener(this);
        pane.setFocusable(true);
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 4, 4));
        pane.setBackground(Color.black);
        ((JComponent) pane).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ImageIcon test1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Volunteering.jpg"));
        Image image = test1.getImage();

    // reduce by 50%
        image = image.getScaledInstance((int) (image.getWidth(null) / 1.18), (int) (image.getHeight(null) / 1.56), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        test1.setImage(image);

   // JButton button = new JButton(test1);
        //pane.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 300);
        app1 = new JButton(test1);
        app1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        pane.add(app1);
        app1.addActionListener(this);
        ImageIcon test2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Aliss.jpg"));
        Image image2 = test2.getImage();
        image2 = image2.getScaledInstance((int) (image2.getWidth(null) / 1.18), (int) (image2.getHeight(null) / 1.56), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        test2.setImage(image2);

        app2 = new JButton(test2);
        // 
        app2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        app2.addActionListener(this);
        pane.add(app2);

        ImageIcon test3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/jobsearch.jpg"));
        Image image3 = test3.getImage();
        image3 = image3.getScaledInstance((int) (image3.getWidth(null) / 1.18), (int) (image3.getHeight(null) / 1.56), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        test3.setImage(image3);
        app3 = new JButton(test3);
        app3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        app3.addActionListener(this);
        pane.add(app3);

        ImageIcon test4 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Connect3.jpg"));
        Image image4 = test4.getImage();
        image4 = image4.getScaledInstance((int) (image4.getWidth(null) / 1.18), (int) (image4.getHeight(null) / 1.56), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        test4.setImage(image4);
        app4 = new JButton(test4);
        app4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        app4.addActionListener(this);
        pane.add(app4);

    }

    public void shutdown() {
        System.exit(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param e
     * @param k
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (e.getSource() == app1) {
            System.out.println("test1");
            web1.run();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == app2) {
            System.out.println("test2");
            web2.run();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == app3) {
            System.out.println("test3");
            web3.run();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == app4) {
            System.out.println("test4");
            web4.run();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        PasswordDialog pass = new PasswordDialog();
        System.out.println("works");
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {

            pass.run();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've got code that we can't test, like the Web? classes. We don't want to see all of  your code, but a [mcve] would be quite nice for both you and us. Other than that, you will want to use key bindings not a key listener (as most all answers to similar questions on this site will tell you).

Comment: Can't show the rest of the classes as they are too big and also im am developing this code for an organisation sorry

Comment: Again, I explicitly didn't ask for the rest of the classes, just your [mcve]. Yes this will require work from you, but it will allow us to be able to answer your question. Again, try to use Key Bindings, and if that doesn't work, then improve your question with your [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to bring up password dialog when VK_ESCAPE is pressed and it works at first . But as soon as any JButtons are pressed focus ignores keyListenrs

Exactly, because KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus. So unless you want to add your escape logic to all your components you should NOT be using a KeyListener. Instead your should be using Key Bindings.

Check out [Escape Key and Dialog](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/) for an example that shows how to close a dialog when the escape key is pressed by adding a binding to the root pane of the dialog.

Obviously your code will be different since you want to display a dialog, but the concept of the key bindings will be the same, you just need to create the custom Action.

Note: by the way I'm not sure about you usage of using the escape key to display a dialog is the best key stroke to use. Usually the escape key is used to close things, like dialogs or open combo boxes or popup menus.

Comment: thanks  the reason im using escape key is to bring up password input dialog wich will then if input correct show the exit bar at top of app . its just a security feature to stop ysers from navigating away from app as it will be general public using it to search for jobs, and welfare help

Comment: @user3188481, So is the question answered. The note about the escape key wasn't really relevant to the answer.